# Transit visa for 2 days stay in Malaysia and Australia

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, australia, malaysia

I am an Indian national and I got my New Zealand student visa, which is new and valid for 2 years. I am planning to stay in Malaysia (Kuala Lumpur) and in Perth Australia for 2 nights just for sightseeing while I continue my journey to New Zealand.

My question is it possible to enter Malaysia and Australia for nights each without a visa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Malaysia**

Nationals of India can avail transit without a visa (twov) and enter in Kuala Lumpur Malaysia with the following conditions:

Source: [Ministry Of Foreign affairs Malaysia](http://www.kln.gov.my/web/che_berne/other_information/-/asset_publisher/2TQe/content/transit-without-visa-for-citizens-of-indian-sub-continental-countries?redirect=%2Fweb%2Fche_berne%2Fother_information)

- TWOV cannot be given to visitors who do not possess visa from 3rd
  country of
             destination as follows:   ·       Australia, ·       New Zealand, ·       United States of America, ·       Japan, ·
  China, ·       Taiwan, ·       South Korea,
- TWOV facility cannot exceed more than 120 hours (5 days).
- TWOV facility is not available at entry point other than Kuala Lumpur International Airport (KLIA) and Low Cost Carrier Terminal (LCCT).
- TWOV cannot be offered to passenger sponsored by airlines other than Malaysia Airlines and Air Asia. At present only MAS and Air Asia have agreed and accepted all terms and conditions imposed by the Malaysian Government.
- TWOV cannot be given to visitors who do not fulfil the following:

·       Valid national passport or internationally recognized travel document;
·       Travel documents valid for more than six (6) months from the date of entry;
·       A return ticket to country of origin;
·       Not listed in the Immigration Department’s suspected list.

- There will be no extension of TWOV facility.

Therefore, as an Indian national you will only be permitted to Kuala Lumpur in Klia or Klia2 for maximum 5 days provided you must have a valid visa from New Zealand, onward ticket for your journey, passport valid for 6 months and must travel through Malaysian airlines or Air Asia.

[Timatic](https://www.klm.com/travel/gb_en/prepare_for_travel/travel_planning/travel_clinic/timatic.htm) also confirms the same. However the only difference is timatic says transit time should be longer than 8 hours and official ministry website doesn't mention anything about minimum 8 hours transit time.

"max. transit For details, click here time of 120 hours, arriving at and
departing from Kuala Lumpur (KUL) on Malaysia Airlines (MH) or Air Asia (AK). When transit time is longer than 8 hours it is
"

**Australia**

From the official  [Australian Government Department of Immigration](https://www.border.gov.au/Lega/Lega/Form/Immi-FAQs/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-through-australia) website you require a transit visa if you are planning to stay in Australia for 2 nights. Indian nationals are not listed in those countries nationals who can transit Australia without applying for a transit visa.

You will be applying for a [Transit Visa Subclass 771](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/771-) and with this visa you can enter and stay in Australia for no longer then 72 hours.

Similarly there are requirements for Indian nationals if applying for a Australian transit visa from India.

Source: [Australian High Commission New Delhi](http://india.embassy.gov.au/ndli/TransitTransit.html)

However you may not be eligible to apply for an transit visa simply for the purpose of tourism. It is clearly written in the website :

"Part of the criteria which must be satisfied for the grant of a Transit visa include that the applicant establishes that their principal purpose in entering Australia is to pass through Australia in transit to another country, and that the applicant intends to remain in Australia no longer than 72 hours. **This criteria cannot be satisfied if the applicant intends a stopover in Australia, for visitation or tourism purposes,** or does not intend to travel on to a third country."

- It is important to remember that the onus is on the applicant to
  satisfy the decision maker that they meet the relevant criteria for
  the grant of the visa.

Therefore you can still apply for a transit visa if you have a legitimate reason to transit without visiting and tourism purposes. Also there is no transit visa fee but you will have to pay service charges for VFS.

Moreover you can always apply for a  visitor visa (subclass 600) lets you visit Australia for tourism. Details regarding this visa can be obtained from [Australian High commission India](http://www.vfsglobal.com/australia/india/tourist.html) and [VFS](http://www.vfsglobal.com/australia/india/tourist.html)

Comment: Be careful. Some countries apply such arrangements only to necessary transits where you are taking the first logical connecting flight out. Here, you wish to stopover longer for a visit, which is not strictly a transit, and need to confirm that a transit visa still applies in this case. In Australia, it sounds like you're not transiting because your main purpose for being there so long is tourism, and the same may apply to Malaysia as well.

Comment: @ZachLipton yes as far as rules are concerned, Ausltralia may not accept simply an application for touristic reasons but in Malaysia he is eliglible to enter for touristic purpose